# How to find string in Android Studio Logcat, not Filter

Tags: android-studio, logcat

I can't figure out how to search for a string in Android Studio Logcat output?  I know how to filter, but that hides surrounding context.  How can I just scroll to the next occurrence of a chosen string?

Answer (score 2):

Open the Logcat tab and press ctrl + f  keys and enter the string you want to search.
You can use the arrow keys on the keyboard to jump to the next and previous result.

Comment: Thanks!  I had tried that (cmd + f on Mac), but it didn't work because the output area didn't have focus.  After clicking within the output area it worked.